# How setup selenium firefox tests on CodeShip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, capybara, codeship

**Intro**
Hi, I'm developing rails application, which use `capybara`, `selenium-webdriver` and `rspec` for tests.

**Problem**
Now I have a functional tests, which runs in firefox (default selenium browser) and works with redirects to other hosts. For example, rspec before hook to get fresh google access token.

Locally on my laptop all tests runs with success:

`bundle exec rspec`

But codeship's builds fails.

**Questions**

Do I need to setup codeship to support "firefox" tests? If yes, how can I do it?

Does codeship supports redirects to other hosts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Codeship supports running selenium tests in the CI , you can find more info here https://documentation.codeship.com/continuous-integration/browser-testing/

However when i tried to run the selenium tests in CI , chrome failed to start 90% of the times , so i am planning to spin up a selenium grid elsewhere and run the tests in codeship